# Error on GraphQL : no provided id but the store already contains an id of

Tags: graphql, apollo

I am very new to GraphQL and Apollo, and I don't understand what is wrong with the 'aliasEmail' field below. When I add this one to the query, I get this error message. When I remove it from the query, everything works perfectly.
It is well defined in 'types.graphql' and is just a simple string field.

```
index.js:2178 Unhandled (in react apollo:Apollo(withRouter(EmailSettingsContainer))) Error: Network 
error: Error writing result to store for query:
  query getCompanyForAliasEmailEditForm($companyId: ID) {
    Company(id: $companyId) {
      name
      isTaxActive
      telFixe
      aliasEmail
      telMobile
      __typename
    }
}

Store error: the application attempted to write an object with no 
provided id but the store already contains an id of 
Company:cje6xkcnxl83u01353a20p1t6 for this object. The selectionSet 
that was trying to be written is:
  Company(id: $companyId) {
    name
    isTaxActive
    telFixe
    aliasEmail
    telMobile
    __typename
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like there's already another query being made elsewhere in the app that also returns the Company object and that query includes the `id` (or `_id`) field, while the query in this case does not. Apollo uses both the typename and id to generate the cache key for your query result (unless dataIdFromObject is used to modify this behavior), and so throws an error when it detects the above discrepancy. Try including the id field in your `getCompanyForAliasEmailEditForm` query.

Comment: thank you Daniel. I added the 'id' to the requested fields in the query and that solved the problem :-)